# Upgrading from Next v11 to Next v12 and getting a memory allocation error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've followed the directions on the Next [blog](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12) I ran `npm i next@latest` as I'm trying to upgrade my project from NextJS v11.1.2 to v12.0.1

My package.json successfully updated to show v12.0.1 - for good measure I also deleted my node_modules folder and my .next folder and re-downloaded all dependencies with npm install to start it cleanly from scratch and it all went smoothly.

Then once I ran `npm run dev` I then received the error below, similar to some older StackOverflow posts reflecting errors/bugs people were receiving in the past with Next v8 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236606/memory-issues-with-next-js), v9 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854361/how-to-allocate-more-memory-to-javascript-heap-using-next-js) and v10 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65379232/tailwind-css-postcss-plugin-with-next-js-10-0-3-gives-javascript-heap-out-of-m)... they've notably gone unsolved.

I can however run `npm run build` with no errors whatsoever. So I cannot get it in development mode for some reason...

I thought I'd just share this bug with people and see if others are also getting the same error. If anyone has any ideas as to how I can fix this, I'd GREATLY appreciate it.

Here is the error I receive when I run `npm run dev`:

```
event - compiled successfully in 5.4s (3124 modules)
wait  - compiling /...
event - compiled successfully in 1720 ms (3157 modules)

<--- Last few GCs --->

[77219:0x110008000]    56149 ms: Scavenge 4065.3 (4137.2) -> 4064.7 (4138.2) MB, 8.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.608, current mu = 0.303) allocation failure
[77219:0x110008000]    56159 ms: Scavenge 4066.1 (4138.2) -> 4065.5 (4142.7) MB, 7.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.608, current mu = 0.303) allocation failure
[77219:0x110008000]    59822 ms: Mark-sweep 4068.6 (4142.7) -> 4065.8 (4144.7) MB, 3653.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.422, current mu = 0.018) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x101366e15 node::Abort() (.cold.1) [/Users/seanmodd/node_modules/node/bin/node]
 2: 0x1000be439 node::Abort() [/Users/seanmodd/node_modules/node/bin/node]
 3: 0x1000be59f node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/Users/seanmodd/node_modules/node/bin/node]
 4: 0x10022f627 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/seanmodd/node_modules/node/bin/node]
```

I've reverted to Next v11.1.2 with ease and will just stick with that for now until I think I can make an adjustment to fix this issue... I would love to try out the edge functions, server components and the faster build times with v12 though so I am missing out!!!!!

There is likely some issue related to other dependencies I have in my project which is causing the conflict... below I've included my package.json just in case, there are quite a lot of packages being used.

```
{
  "name": "@minimal/minimal-kit-react",
  "author": "minimals.cc",
  "version": "2.6.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3222",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "3.4.15",
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "1.18",
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@fontsource/alata": "^4.5.0",
    "@fontsource/barlow": "^4.5.0",
    "@fontsource/inter": "^4.5.0",
    "@fontsource/karla": "^4.5.0",
    "@fontsource/poppins": "^4.5.0",
    "@fontsource/public-sans": "^4.5.0",
    "@fontsource/raleway": "^4.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timeline": "^5.9.0",
    "@hookform/devtools": "^4.0.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.0",
    "@iconify/icons-ant-design": "^1.1.0",
    "@iconify/icons-eva": "^1.1.0",
    "@iconify/icons-ic": "^1.1.10",
    "@iconify/icons-simple-icons": "^1.1.46",
    "@iconify/react": "^3.0.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.21",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.47",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/utils": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.0.0-beta.1",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.0.19",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.5.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.18.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@turf/bbox": "^6.5.0",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.1.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.28.3",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.20.0",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "d3-array": "^3.0.2",
    "d3-scale": "^4.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.24.0",
    "deck.gl": "^8.5.8",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "emoji-mart": "^3.0.0",
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "highlight.js": "^11.2.0",
    "history": "^5.0.1",
    "i18next": "^20.6.1",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.14",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lazysizes": "^5.3.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "madge": "^5.0.1",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.4.1",
    "next": "^11.1.2",
    "notistack": "^1.0.6-next.3",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.4",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.7",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.4.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.1.2",
    "react-highlight": "^0.14.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.15.3",
    "react-i18next": "^11.12.0",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.4",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^8.32.1",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-map-gl": "^6.1.17",
    "react-markdown": "^7.0.1",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-resize-aware": "^3.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.4",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.0",
    "react-spring": "^9.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "rehype-highlight": "^5.0.0",
    "rehype-raw": "^6.1.0",
    "simplebar": "^5.3.5",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.5",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "stylis": "^4.0.10",
    "stylis-plugin-rtl": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "worker-loader": "^3.0.8",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.31.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.31.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-wesbos": "2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.25.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: How much memory does your system have?

Comment: Here is the [screenshot of my memory](https://cln.sh/BcYqXL) used and available... it's fine I think? @AKX right?

Comment: That looks fine. You may need to tweak Node's memory settings á la https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495296/51685 ...

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I have followed the instructions.

_I actually increased it twice by running both_ 
`NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 node`
_as well as:_
`NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=9192 node`
and  as seen [here](https://cln.sh/2T1kEy) and [here](https://cln.sh/4USMnp) , _my terminal is reflecting the successful increase in heap sizes made to my node_,
yet after all that I still receive the same error when trying to upgrade to Next v12... not sure why

Comment: @AKX in case it helps, I've included the entire response [here](https://cln.sh/e6XXgC). Also, I just noticed that **a full Node.js error / diagnostic report which gets generated each time I try and run** `npm run dev` with Next v12 - the [gist which contains the full error report is here](https://gist.github.com/seanmodd/7359c3d7ea46df9e9b938c4c5772e528)... I've never had an error where Node has auto-generated such a diagnostic report so I think it should have some good nuggets of info somewhere in there...

Comment: You're apparently using Node 13 (`"node": "13.10.0"`) - definitely try upgrading to 16.x (the LTS version) or 17.

Comment: Ugh, man this is so frutstrating lol. I did that, just upgraded to Node LTS which is 16.13 and still getting this same error!